# OpenVPN encryption and authorization issues

Tags: networking, vpn, encryption, openvpn, authentication

I have configured my OpenVPN server and client by reading various tutorials. The configuration I'm using currently is the following:

For the server:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

And for the client:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote my-server-1 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth ta.key 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

**Now there are two problems I'm facing:**

1) The connection from my client to the server looks fine; however, I keep getting this message:

```
******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
```

But I don't understand why this comes up. I want my connection to be encrypted, and I worked for that, and I created and used all necessary keys (as you see in the conf files).

2) I went to my laptop (which is not the client), and installed OpenVPN using my apt-get, and simply connected with the server (with no config whatsoever)... and guess what... it connected! Now that freaked me out! It looked like everyone can connect to my OpenVPN server! The log I got from this connection is this (after removing time-stamps):

```
OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Feb 27 2013
IMPORTANT: OpenVPN's default port number is now 1194, based on an official port number assignment by IANA.  OpenVPN 2.0-beta16 and earlier used 5000 as the default port.
NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]93.111.222.121:1194
event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
SIGINT[hard,] received, process exiting
```

Could you please explain what this means?

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: Could you post the log data from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you starting OpenVPN?  It sounds like you're invoking it in such a way that it's either reading the wrong configuration file or not reading one at all.

I believe on my system I use `openvpn {config-file-name.ovpn}`.  A plain `openvpn` may produce this.  You need to tell it what configuration file to use.

Comment: Thank you. I just had to specify the config file name for my client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that to the server and client config files

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA256

you can use any other cipher too..